# How do I get rid of a NULL segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am creating a linked list program in C and I keep on getting a segmentation fault.  I've narrowed the problem down to a few lines of code and I believe it has to do with checking for NULL. How can I fix this? Here's the code:

```
typedef struct node
{
  int contents;
  struct node *nextNode;
}  Node;



deleteNode(Node *currentNode)
{

  while((currentNode->contents) != NULL)
  {
    //.....Do Stuff.....
    currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: On a side note ... if this deleteNode function is supposed to delete a node from a linked list, it can't. You can't delete a node from a singly liked list with only a pointer to the node you want to delete (unless your root node is accessible globally, or course)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try checking to make sure that `currentNode` isn't `NULL` at the start of `deleteNode()`. I.e.

```
deleteNode(Node *currentNode)
{
    if (currentNode == NULL) return;
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is as I suspect, `currentNode` is a null pointer. Just ensure that `currentNode` is not null before you attempt to access it.

```
deleteNode(Node* currentNode)
{
    while ((currentNode != NULL) && (currentNode->contents != NULL))
    {
        /* ... */
        currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm suspicious that this line:

```
while((currentNode->contents) != NULL)
```

is comparing the `contents` field of your `Node` structure, which is an `int`, with `NULL`...  I would guess that this was supposed to be checking `currentNode->nextNode`instead!

So, probably: none of your `contents` are zero, so this test is true for every item in the list.  Then the last item has a NULL `currentNode->nextNode`, which is assigned to `currentNode`, and it blows up dereferencing it the next time round the loop.

Answer (score 0):

what happens when currentNode is NULL?. It is dereferencing a NULL memory in the while condition.